# opacity vs fill-opacity in svg

Tags: javascript, css, svg

What is the difference in `opacity` vs `fill-opacity` in SVG?

I referred the docs for [fill-opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill-opacity) and [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/opacity) but I am confused what is meant by

> fill-opacity: opacity of the content of the current object

vs

> opacity: transparency of an object

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The difference is exactly what the name indicates :). `fill-opacity` is applicable only to the `fill` of the element (or in other words, just its background), `stroke-opacity` is applicable only to the `stroke` whereas the `opacity` is applicable to both.

The `opacity` is kind of a post-processing operation. That is, the element (or group) as a whole (the fill + stroke) is rendered and then the transparency is adjusted based on the opacity setting whereas the `fill-opacity` and `stroke-opacity` are intermediate steps, so the transparency is individually added to the stroke and fill. So when `stroke-opacity` and `fill-opacity` are used together, the result would still not be the same as using `opacity` (because the transparency on the fill will let the fill color show through wherever they overlap). You can see the difference visually in the first two elements below.

Also as indicated by Robert (in comments), `fill-opacity` doesn't apply to `image` whereas `opacity` does work.

```css
svg {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/1);
  height: 100vh;
}
polygon {
  stroke-width: 3;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 40 190'>
  <polygon points='10,10 30,10 30,30 10,30' fill='steelblue' stroke='crimson' opacity='0.5' />
  <polygon points='10,40 30,40 30,60 10,60' fill='steelblue' stroke='crimson' fill-opacity='0.5' stroke-opacity='0.5' />
  <polygon points='10,70 30,70 30,90 10,90' fill='steelblue' stroke='crimson' fill-opacity='0.5' />
  <polygon points='10,100 30,100 30,120 10,120' fill='steelblue' stroke='crimson' stroke-opacity='0.5' />
  <image xlink:href='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/3' x='8.5' y='130' width='23' height='23' stroke='crimson' opacity='0.5' />
  <image xlink:href='http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/3' x='8.5' y='160' width='23' height='23' stroke='crimson' fill-opacity='0.5' />
</svg>
```

---

In the CSS world you can think of it as something like in the below snippet. (*Note that I am not saying they are equal, **there are subtle differences between SVG and CSS**. It is just an attempt to explain what those SVG attributes would translate to in CSS.*)

```css
div {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 20vh;
  margin: 30px auto;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 2vw;
}
div:nth-of-type(1) {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: rgba(70, 130, 180, 1);
  border: .35vw solid rgba(220, 20, 60, 1);
}
div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: rgba(70, 130, 180, 0.5);
  border: .35vw solid rgba(220, 20, 60, 1);
}
div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: rgba(70, 130, 180, 1);
  border: .35vw solid rgba(220, 20, 60, 0.5);
}
body {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/600/600/nature/1);
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson: Oh yeah. Wanted to add a sample for that but seem to have forgot. Per my understanding the only difference would be that `opacity='0.5'` is done as something like post processing and so it will be like the fill + stroke painted and then opacity reduced whereas the other two are like intermediate options and so when both are used together the stroke's opacity will show a bit of the fill's color through (where they overlap). Are there any other differences?

Comment: Correct + opacity applies to images, fill/stroke opacity doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, this clears my confusion. Thank you @RobertLongson for the additional info.

Answer (score 11):

In addition to affecting which parts of each individual element are affected (e.g. fill versus stroke) another difference is what happens when elements overlap within a group. `opacity` affects the transparency of the group as a whole while `fill-opacity` affects the transparency of the individual elements within the group. One consequence of this is that when elements within such a group overlap, there is a compounding effect in the region of overlap when `fill-opacity` is used but not when `opacity` is used. This is demonstrated in the image below when a (fill-)opacity of 0.5 is applied to either each element within a group or to the group itself.

[image]

```html
<svg height="200">
  <g transform="translate(0, 0)">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40"   fill-opacity="0.5"/>
    <rect x="30" y="30" width="40" height="40"   fill-opacity="0.5"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(80, 0)"                fill-opacity="0.5">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40"/>
    <rect x="30" y="30" width="40" height="40"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0, 80)">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40"        opacity="0.5"/>
    <rect x="30" y="30" width="40" height="40"        opacity="0.5"/>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(80, 80)"                    opacity="0.5">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40"/>
    <rect x="30" y="30" width="40" height="40"/>
  </g>
  <text transform="translate(170,45)">fill-opacity</text>
  <text transform="translate(170,125)">opacity</text>
  <text transform="translate(10,175)">applied to</text>
  <text transform="translate(0,190)">each element</text>
  <text transform="translate(90,175)">applied to</text>
  <text transform="translate(103,190)">group</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

`fill-opacity` controls the opacity for the fill color. `opacity` controls the opacity of the entire thing.

Take a look at this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/9mvrL66g/

Comment: Thank you for the demo.. that helps

Answer (score 2):

I found this table helpful when considering which flavor of `opacity` to use with `SVG`. Let's not forget about `stroke-opacity` and `stop-opacity`.

```
|    Attribute   |             Explanation            |              Applies to:             | 
|:--------------:|:----------------------------------:|:------------------------------------:|
| opacity        | The overall opacity of the element.| Everything but gradient stops        |   
| fill-opacity   | The opacity of the fill paint.     | Elements with the attribute 'fill'   | 
| stroke-opacity | The opacity of the stroke paint.   | Elements with the attribute 'stroke' |
| stop-opacity   | The opacity of the gradient stop.  | Gradient stops                       |
```

Comment: What about flood-opacity?

Comment: Thank you. The table is very helpful.