# How to use transparent SVGs in jasper report and export to pdf

Tags: svg, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm trying to export jasper report to pdf using partially opaque SVGs, but in the pdf the opaque are solid white-ish.

The image expression is:

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.SimpleRenderToImageAwareDataRenderer.getInstance(byte[] data)]]></imageExpression>
```

In the background it seems jasper is using Apache BatikRenderer and XML Graphics.
Here are even examples of transparency support:

https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/trunk/graphics.html#svg

According to this link, transparency should be supported: https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/dev/svg.html

There is even a pdf-example which works with transparency.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at how the SVG in the example defined transparency, I noticed my SVGs differed:

In the example "fill-opacity" is used, while my SVGs used simply "opacity".

By changing opacity to fill-opacity in the SVG, the transparency also worked in the pdf generated by jasper. (Related thread
[svg opacity vs fill-opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759898/opacity-vs-fill-opacity-in-svg))

Now I faced 2 options:
One solution would be to write a script that modifies the svg xml and replaces opacity with fill-opacity.
Another option was to see if the source of the SVGs could be changed so that I would get SVGs using fill-opacity in the first place.
The source outputting SVGs in my case was matplotlib, and the next question was how to get matplotlib to output SVG with fill-opacity instead of opacity: